# Nemo File Manager - Disable Expandable Folders

Tags: nautilus, dolphin, nemo

I've been using the Nemo File Manager inside of Linux Mint and Ubuntu, and there's always been one thing that bothers me - the little triangle next to each folder that lets me expand it. Albeit this feature is nice for most, I'd like to disable it. I've searched high and low for how to do so and have found nothing. I've tried dconf-editor, gconf-editor, Nemo Settings, changing settings in .config, and all sorts of things. I've noticed that there seems to be no option to change this anywhere from what I can see.

If anyone knows how, please let me know!

Comment: You can change the view to Compact View with Ctrl+3.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Unfortunately, Compact View is nice, but I don't like the wrap-around sorting. I want a single list top to bottom, but without the "Expand Folder" triangle.